# Web scraping spider

Tags: python, performance, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on my first web scraping project and I need to scrape a lot of websites. With my current code it takes more than a day but for my project I need to scan the same websites every 5 days or so and 1 day of scanning is too long. From what I read so far my options are threading or something like an asynchronous requests library like [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests).
Here is my code:

```
def sortiment(Supermarkt_link, Supermarkt_name):
    with open("progress.txt", "r") as t: 
        lines = t.readlines()
        paused_loop_start = int(lines[0])   
        for e in range(paused_loop_start + 1, get_max_product_number(Supermarkt_link) ):
            json_list = []
            page = requests.get(f"https://www.supermarktcheck.de{Supermarkt_link}sortiment/?page={e}")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
            products_list = soup.find_all("a", class_="h3", href=True)
            for single_product in products_list: 
                product_string = single_product["href"]
                product_page = requests.get(f"https://www.supermarktcheck.de/{product_string}")
```

This code scrapes a landing page and than scans each individual page on that landing page for information that are then saved into a database.

Comment: What does `get_max_product_number` do? Can you post the entire script?

Comment: Please add all the imports required to run this script.

Answer (score 1):

Even without changing this code, using [sessions](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/) could boost performance.

And indeed you need to add some kind of parallel processing. Python has different options for that, and there are many different approaches - [example](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/speed-up-web-scraping-with-concurrency-in-python#scraping-with-asyncio).

If you can spread concurrent requests among different websites this is even better. You can normally crawl more than one page at a time on the same webserver but you don't want to overwhelm the server. And quite likely, there is **rate limiting** in place. Consider yourself lucky if you don't have to deal with Cloudflare captchas.

It's not clear what the purpose of `json_list` is, or `paused_loop_start`, or how `get_max_product_number` works. Maybe this function is slowing you down further.

Answer (score 0):

Using asynchronous requests is a go to method.

But you can also check out [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Why not take advantage of multi-core CPU's to maximize performance.